# How to dispose System.Drawing.Font in parallel threading?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dispose, system.drawing

We generate 1000s of audit reports per hour using parallel threads. While generating we are making use of the System.Drawing.Font for writing text to pdfs (syncfusion). As we need to make use of different fonts (8-10 types) for each audit, it is causing noticeable memory hikes in the production server. To avoid this we tried disposing them after each pdf is being saved to a memory stream.

```
using (var loadedDocument = new PdfDocument()) 
{
    var indexPage = loadedDocument.Pages.Add();
    var header = indexPage.Graphics; 
    var calibri35Font = new Font("Calibri", 35); 
    var calibri35PdfFont = new PdfTrueTypeFont(calibri35Font); 
    var stringCenterFormat = new PdfStringFormat { Alignment = PdfTextAlignment.Center }; 
    header.DrawString("AUDIT REPORT \n", calibri35PdfFont, PdfBrushes.Black, new PointF(250, 50), stringCenterFormat);
    --------
    --------
    --------
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    { 
        loadedDocument.Save(stream);
    } 
    calibri35Font.Dispose(); 
    calibri35PdfFont.Dispose();                        
}
```

However, this is causing null exception issues due to parallel threads try to load the same font.

The question is how to safely dispose the fonts without breaking parallel processes that make use of the same resource and is there a better way to address the memory issues.

Comment: You can use `using( var calibri35Font = new Font("Calibri", 35))` to not call dispose your self. But I will go the other way don't dispose the font. Never. Cache them somewhere and lock it when you use it.

Comment: Are you using the same Font-object in multiple threads? Your example does not show any threading, and I would have expected it to be safe to create, use and dispose a font if it is all done on the same thread.

Comment: I would still try to create a 'font cache'; It can be as large as you need as long as you reuse the fonts already there. A naming scheme and a Dictionary<string, Font> may do the job..

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TaW, could you please provide me an example on how to create a font cache

Comment: Just like I said: Start with a naming scheme that lets you create a unique name (string) for each font/variant you need, say, family name + Size + atrributes... Then a Dictionary to hold the Fonts with the name you created as key. It should be accessible for each of your threads and if the key is already there you can use the font, otherwise add it. You will have to take care of the locking but otherwise each font will be created and stored only once..